# Print the elements of a txt column

Tags: php, list, text, multiple-columns

Got this code php

```
$data ='
one;uno
two;dos
three;tres
four;cuatro
'
```

I want to **print** the first column in a row, separating elements with comma and aspace, to obtain this result:

```
one, two, three, four
```

Any help please? I'm doing this but I can`t:

```
<?php

$data ='
one;uno
two;dos
three;tres
four;cuatro
';

$line = explode("\n", $data);
for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {        

$item = explode(";", $line[$i]);

$coma = implode(', ', $item[0{);

echo $coma;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this modified version of your code

```
$data ='one;uno
two;dos
three;tres
four;cuatro';
$coma=array();
$line = explode("\n", $data);

for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {        
$item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
$coma[]=  $item[0];
}

echo implode(',',$coma);
```

Comment: 1- data variable has no leading and trailing line feed, 2-coma variable is made array while assigned item[0] instead of implode and 3- at last echo implode instead of plan coma variable